# using Sybase in Silex API with Doctrine

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, silex

I'm trying to connect my silex API to a sybase database. For that, I installed a PDO Driver via composer. The PDO Driver is working like a charm in another project of my company that uses Symfony2.

I then configured my Database as follows:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver_class'    => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODbLib\Driver',
        'host'            => '********',
        'port'            => '********',
        'dbname'          => '********',
        'user'            => '********',
        'password'        => '********',
        'charset'         => 'UTF8'
    ),
));
```

Of course, the asterisks are real values in my code. What happens now is that my host is continuously loading and not giving back any result as soon as I try to execute a query.

Did anybody encountered this problem before?